# Integrating data from multiple objects in one view in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view

Hi I have three classes as objects which go into the database.

```
public class Employees
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string SocialSecurityNumber{ get; set;}
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set;}
}

public class Education
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string EmployeeId { get; set;}
    public string EducationLevel{ get; set;} // this will be a drop down list
    public string University { get; set;}
    public string FieldOfStudy { get; set;}
}

public class Experience
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public int EmployeeId { get; set;}
    public string Employer{ get; set;}
    public DateTime From { get; set;}
    public DateTime To { get; set;}
    public string JobRole { get; set;}
}
```

Then I have the DBContext class defined as:

```
public class AppDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee>Employees{ get; set;}
    public DbSet<Education> Educations { get; set;}
    public DbSet<Experience> Experiences {get; set;}
}
```

What my app needs to do now is offer a Create Employee form on the home page which lets the user fill in all the details pertaining to him. That is Employee details , Education and Experience against the employee object in one single form in Home/Index View.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create new class in the Model folder.
2. Add 3 properties for Employees, Education and Experience **and build your project.**
3. In the action method in the controller (Index for example), fill that class with your data and 'return View(yourFilledClass)'
4. right click on the controller method (Index) and add View
5. Bind that view to the new class and select Details in the dropdown
6. Now you have a view for displaying all the details of the new class you've just populated
7. It's quite the same for Edit, delete and add

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Well I tried to do just that, using that class as a View Model, but I can't access the properties of these individual objects in the View.

Comment: Infact what happens with this View Model approach is that in the View I'm not able to access the individual properties of the objects that I've defined. Also in the controller which table do I access as all the relevant object are on different tables, since each object translates into one table.

Comment: @user2377475, The idea is to construct a ViewModel for your purpose with public properties. In your case, it contains 3 properties for your classes.
Your controller should populate this ViewModel with actual data from the DB and send it to the View.
Why can't you access those properties? Can you post your code?